# Stop sub process of PowerShell

Tags: powershell

When running a script in powershell, it creates a child process. How can I kill that process.

When I use `Get-Process` it only shows the Parent process.

I have included a screen shot of the process (Highlighted in yellow) I would like to stop / kill

I have no code currently for this part as I am unsure what to use, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The picture shows the application view. Go to powershell command shell and use "Get-Process"

Comment: This question belongs on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).